# Use AlarmManager to start Activity at Specific time

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I get a json  from a server contains a configuration of application names, file names. which presents the resources I add  icons of my ressources to layout corresponding to creat session. Now I want to add in this json a validity date of session. If this date is not valid I can not launch my `GridView`and I have a message to say that the session is no longer valid. My problem is what to use for this service or not and to use a `Handler` or not. I know I must use `AlarmManager` to start a `Service` at Specific time. But if you have an example I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

check service and broadcast receivers for Android:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

When do you "...get a json from a server..."?? First check if it is necessary to use a service